# Python's collection.deque does not seem to be thread-safe with multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-2.7, thread-safety, python-multiprocessing, deque

I am working in a small piece of code that is intended to work as follows:

- An arbitrary number of processes (e.g. 10) is to be run.
- Because I have two threads, I want to run them two at a time.
- I want them to read a value from a queue. The queue only contains two different values, and I want the two processes running at the same time to read these different values.

For instance, consider the next sample code:

```
import collections
import time

q = collections.deque()
q.append(0)
q.append(1)

def f(i):
    d = q.popleft()
    print d
    time.sleep(1)
    q.append(d)

from multiprocessing import Pool
t = Pool(2)
t.map(f, range(10))
```

When running this, I expect the first pair of processes to read 0 and 1 respectively. I don't really mind the order in which they are printed (either 0, 1 or 1, 0). However, the output is as follows:

```
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
1
0
1
```

Why is this happening if deque is thread-safe? Also, the first 8 values are printed 2 at a time every 1 second, but for the last 2 values there is a 1-second pause as well between them. To clarify this, let me draw 1-sec pauses as hyphens:

```
0
0
-
1
1
-
0
0
-
1
1
-
0
-
1
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The individual actions `pop()` and `append()` are thread-safe but not multiple calls to a `deque` that requires some high-level synchronization. And you can't tell if this just the order the `print's` are executed.

Comment: The processes aren't even working on the same deque. They each have their own copy. This isn't threading; we're not working in a single shared address space with shared objects here.

Comment: But I do know (because they are printed before the first 1-sec pause), that the first two 0s in the output are the first two processes, which have read from the queue (in parallel). How can they both read 0?

Comment: I see @user2357112. However, the same behavior is happening when defining `q` as `global`.

Comment: @baldo: `global` doesn't mean anything like what you think it means. It's useless here. You need to use the inter-process communication tools provided by the multiprocessing module.

Comment: Good video - [Thinking about Concurrency, Raymond Hettinger](https://youtu.be/Bv25Dwe84g0)

Answer (score 0):

Processes do not share memory.

In your example, each and every process works on its own copy of the deque. There is no synchronization between them at all.

You can use a [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) object to achieve the correct result.